# convert Fragment to Android.Support.V4.App.Fragment

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I have this code:

```
using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.OS;
using MvvmCross;
using MvvmCross.Droid.Support.V7.AppCompat;
using MvvmCross.Forms.Views;
using MvvmCross.ViewModels;
using System;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android;

[....]

private void SetupPage()
        {
            if (_pageType == null) throw new NullReferenceException("ContentPage type can't be null. Call SetTypes() before creating the Intent");
            if (_viewModelType == null) throw new NullReferenceException("ViewModel type can't be null. Call SetTypes() before creating the Intent");

            var viewModel = Mvx.IoCProvider.Resolve(_viewModelType) as IMvxViewModel;

            var page = Activator.CreateInstance(_pageType) as MvxContentPage ?? 
                       Mvx.IoCProvider.Resolve(_pageType) as MvxContentPage;

            if(page == null || viewModel == null)
                return;
            
            page.ViewModel = viewModel;

            var fragment = page.CreateSupportFragment(this);
            SupportFragmentManager
                .BeginTransaction()
                .Replace(Resource.Id.fragment_container, fragment)
                .Commit();
        }
```

I try to update **var fragment** with **Android.Support.V4.App.Fragment fragment** but I have this error at this line:

***Cannot implicitly convert type 'AndroidX.Fragment.App.Fragment' to 'Android.Support.V4.App.Fragment'***

[image]

Comment: Is there a particular reason you need to use android.support classes?  If not, just use the androidx classes; they're newer.

Comment: I have the same error on .Repalce(..., fragment). On fragment

Answer (score 0):

Please use the `AndroidX.Fragment.App.Fragment` instead of `AndroidX.Fragment.V4.App.Fragment`.

Try to replace the following code:

```
        Android.Support.V4.App.Fragment  fragment = page.CreateSupportFragment(this);
        SupportFragmentManager
            .BeginTransaction()
            .Replace(Resource.Id.fragment_container, fragment)
            .Commit();
```

with:

```
        AndroidX.Fragment.App.Fragment scanFragment = page.CreateSupportFragment(this);
        SupportFragmentManager
            .BeginTransaction()
            .Replace(Resource.Id.fragment_container, fragment)
            .Commit();
```

Comment: yes but the .replace still wants Android.Support.V4.App.Fragment

Comment: That would then suggest that line using MvvmCross.Droid.Support.V7.AppCompat is also incorrect as is not using AndroidX.Fragment.App.Fragment.